# Adding comments/notes

Tags: mysql, triggers, warnings

I have a trigger as follows:

```
DELIMITER //
create trigger highStockInsert
After insert on inventory
for each row Begin
if new.currentStock > 250 then Insert INTO higherStockList VALUES (new.prodName, new.StockCount, new.storeName, 'High Alert');
end if; end
// ;
```

Now when this trigger is act upon I would like mysql to give a message of some sorts, I was messing around with SQLSTATE but if this is triggered the table doesn't update it just blocks the whole insert statement from going through. I was wondering if its possible for the new row to be added but still give off a notification. *I was looking if its possible to trigger a warning but found no luck either*.

Thanks!

Comment: Push a message into a results table and select that later?

Comment: See [SIGNAL statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/signal.html), examples for `SQLSTATE '01000'`.

Comment: @Akina where do I view this message after I add 

SIGNAL SQLSTATE '01000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT='TEST';

Comment: In `SHOW WARNINGS;`.